# Search issue on chosen dropdown using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am implementing chosen dropdown in my project. But I have some problem which I want to solve.

Before proceeding, let me give you the jQuery fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jHvmg/278/

Now I have a dropdown like this

```
<select id="drp_menu">
    <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="Option 5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

As you can see in the fiddle:

1) If I write `"Opt"` in the searchbox then the list is filtered showing all the options.

2) If I write `" 1"` it shows `"Option 1"`

3) If I write `"1"` it shows `"Option 1"`

4) If I write `"ptio"` then it states `"No results"`

5) If I write `"tio"` then it states `"No result"`

I want to results if words typed in the searchbox matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `{ search_contains: true }` and Enjoy :)

### JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#drp_menu').chosen({ search_contains: true });                      
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jHvmg/279/)

Comment: thanks.... i have one more question... if i have 50 dropdowns, and editing them one by one will be problematic.... how can i do it all at a time?? say something in the chosen_js file?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$('#drp_menu').chosen();
```

with

```
$('#drp_menu').chosen({search_contains:true});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jHvmg/282/)

Just look for the [documentation](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html) for `configuration options` like this